# The equation $\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{x+y}=a^xb^y$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $a, b \in (0, \infty)$, $a<b$. Prove that the equation
$$\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{x+y}=a^xb^y$$
has at least one solution in $(a, b)$. Some suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to prove that for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $a,b \in (0,\infty)$ such that $((a+b)/2)^{x+y} = a^x b^y$?

Comment: @Marvis: not really. The text of the problem is somewhat different. For instance, I think it's possible you may choose  $x, y \in R$ such that there is no a,b so that  $((a+b)/2)^{x+y} = a^x b^y$. (I just suppose that, but I might be wrong). The text above is the original text of the problem the way I received it.

Comment: The solutions are pairs $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, yet the solution space is supposed to be an interval in $\mathbb{R}$.  I'm not sure what is meant.  It is probably best to get clarification from the original source as to what the problem actually is asking you to do.

Comment: Is $(a,b)$ an open interval or a pair?

Comment: @Michael Joyce: if you choose any $a,b \in (0,\infty)$ with $a<b$, then there are x, y $\in (a, b)$ such that $((a+b)/2)^{x+y} = a^x b^y$. This is the way I understand the text above. Sorry, I'm not a mathematician and cannot explain better than that.

Comment: @glebovg: it's an open interval.

Comment: Well you definitely want to start by taking the logarithm of both sides ...

Comment: @MichaelJoyce: OK. Thanks. I'll go this way.

Comment: Hint: You can find a solution with $x+y=1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a direct usage of the intermediate value theorem.

Let $f(t)=a^{1-t}b^t$. Then $f(t)$ is continuous and $f(0)=a$ and $f(1)=b$. Since $\frac{a+b}2$ is between $a$ and $b$, there must be a $t_0\in[0,1]$ such that $$f(t_0)=\frac{a+b}2$$
Let $x=1-t$ and $y=t$.

Indeed, we could just solve for $t_0$ by writing $f(t)=a\left(\frac{b}a\right)^t$ and yielding $t_0=\log_{b/a} \frac{a+b}{2a}$

Comment: Too awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The equation can be solved for $x/y$ in terms of $b/a$ as 
$$ \frac{x}{y} = \frac{\ln(b/a)}{\ln\left(\dfrac{1+b/a}{2}\right)} - 1 $$

The statement that there exist $x,y \in (a,b)$ that satisfy the equation is
equivalent to the assertion that for all $t > 1$,

$$ 1/t \le \frac{\ln(t)}{\ln\left(\dfrac{1+t}{2}\right)} - 1 \le t $$

Let $$\eqalign{f(t) &= t \ln \left(\dfrac{1+t}{2}\right)\cr
               g(t) &= \ln(t) - \ln \left(\dfrac{1+t}{2}\right)\cr
               h(t) &= \dfrac{1}{t} \ln \left(\dfrac{1+t}{2}\right)\cr}$$
Then we want to show that $f(t) > g(t) > h(t)$ for $t > 1$.
As $t \to 0$, all three have limit $0$.  So  it suffices to show that $f'(t) - g'(t) > 0$ and $g'(t) > h'(t)$ for $t > 1$.

In fact we have $$f'(t) - g'(t) = \ln\left(\dfrac{1+t}{2}\right) + 1 - \frac{1}{t} \ge  1 - \frac{1}{t} > 0$$
$$ g'(t) - h'(t) = \frac{1}{t^2}  \ln\left(\dfrac{1+t}{2}\right) > 0$$

Comment: thank your for your solution (+1)